Undeclared identifier 'longTakeProfit' in Pine Script
The error is for longStopLoss and longTakeProfit, shortStopLoss and shortTakeProfit. I double checked the original definition and its the same. I think its because theyre part of different functions but I dont know how to fix it.
if (longCondition)
    longStopLoss = close * (1 - stopLossPerc)
    longTakeProfit = close * (1 + takeProfitPerc)
if (shortCondition)
    shortStopLoss = close * (1 + stopLossPerc)
    shortTakeProfit = close * (1 - takeProfitPerc)


if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Take Profit/Stop Loss", from_entry="Long", limit = longTakeProfit, stop = longStopLoss)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("Take Profit/Stop Loss", from_entry="Short", limit = shortTakeProfit, stop = shortStopLoss)


Try the Reassignment operator.
something like that:
var longStopLoss    = 0.0
var longTakeProfit  = 0.0

if (longCondition)
    longStopLoss    := close * (1 - stopLossPerc)
    longTakeProfit  := close * (1 + takeProfitPerc)

